# ¿Para qué sirve <?= en PHP?

Tags: php, php5

¿En PHP para qué sirve esto?

```
<?=
?>
```

¿Y qué diferencia hay respecto a esta forma?

```
<?php
?>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<?= ?>
```

Es el equivalente de hacer

```
<?php echo; ?>
```

, luego hacer

```
<?= 'hola mundo' ?>
```

Es el equivalente de hacer

```
<?php 
    echo 'hola mundo'; 
?>
```

Por otro lado

```
<?php 
?>
```

Es la forma estándar de abrir etiquetas php. Existe una forma abreviada usando

```
<?
?>
```

Pero como ya han comentado, dependen de parámetros en la configuración de php y no siempre están disponibles.

Answer (score 11):

Como aportación, quisiera responder a tu pregunta citando las indicaciones del Manual de PHP, dejando los enlaces como referencia.

### `<?=  ?>`

Según el [Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) es una **abreviatura** que equivale a `<? echo ?>`.

> ... la abreviatura `<?=` ... la cual es lo mismo que `<? echo`. Antes de
>   PHP 5.4.0 el uso de esta abreviatura requería que `short_open_tag`
>   estuviese activada. Desde PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` siempre está disponible.

---

### `<?php  ?>`

Son las **etiquetas de apertura y cierre** usadas para interpretar código PHP.

De lo indicado en el [Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), es importante subrayar lo siguiente:

- Estas etiquetas ofrecen la posibilidad de embeber código PHP en todo tipo de documentos
- Si estamos escribiendo un archivo que sólo contiene código php es conveniente omitir la etiqueta de cierre `?>`
- Se permite la etiqueta de apertura abreviada `<?`, pero se **desaconseja su uso**

> Cuando PHP analiza un fichero, busca las etiquetas de apertura y
>   cierre, que son `<?php` y `?>`, y que indican a PHP dónde empezar y
>   finalizar la interpretación del código. Este mecanismo **permite
>   embeber a PHP en todo tipo de documentos**, ya que todo lo que esté
>   fuera de las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de PHP será ignorado por
>   el analizador.
>
> PHP también permite la etiqueta de apertura abreviada `<?` (la cual
>   está **desaconsejada** debido a que sólo está disponible si se
>   habilita con la directiva `short_open_tag` del fichero de
>   configuración `php.ini`, o si PHP se configuró con la opción
>   `--enable-short-tags` ).
>
> Si un fichero contiene solamente código de PHP, **es preferible omitir
>   la etiqueta de cierre de PHP al final del mismo**. Así se previene la
>   adición de espacios en blanco o nuevas líneas accidentales después de
>   la etiqueta de cierre, lo cual causaría efectos no deseados debido a
>   que PHP comenzará la salida del búfer cuando no había intención por
>   parte del programador de enviar ninguna salida en ese punto del
>   script.

Answer (score 3):

`<?= ... ?>` Es la abreviatura de `<?php echo?>`.

`<?php ... ?>` Es la forma verbosa de introducir código php.

`<? ... ?>`Es la forma abreviada de `<?php ... ?>`.

Es mejor utilizar la segunda siempre que sea posible ya que la primera y la tercera pueden no estar disponibles

Puedes ver si la forma corta está habilitada o no en el fichero `php.ini`, por la propiedad `short_open_tag`. Aunque a partir de [PHP 5.4.0](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) la directiva `<?= ... ?>`siempre está disponible.

Comment: Creo que estas en un error, la primera equivale al echo ... mientras que la segunda no.

Comment: La primera y la segunda no son lo mismo. La primera forma abreviada de hacer `echo`, la segunda es la forma de abrir etiquetas de php. La diferencia es que la segunda puede contener código ejecutable php, cualquiera que sea, y la primera incluye un valor que será imprimido por la función `echo`.

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora me quedó claro

Comment: ¿Porqué poner un negativo? ¿Hay algo que moleste de la respuesta?

Answer (score 3):

En php los símbolos `<?= $variable ?>` indican una abreviatura de `<?php echo variable; ?>`

Esta característica está habilitada por defecto desde la versión [5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)