# Paginación php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hola chicos me encuentro con un problema; les platico:

Realicé un buscador de registros, para mostrar datos que tengo en mi BD, me los muestra de manera perfecta, he colocado un botón para ver mas detalles del registro, entiendo que tengo que mandar el id para que me pueda mostrar los datos específicos del registro que busqué.

Ahora, aquí el problema, al paginar los resultados y dar clic en siguiente pagina me aparece que la variable no existe o no está definida. ¿Cómo le hago para que la variable pueda pasar de página en página y pueda usarla para realizar consultas?

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pagina_v4/css/2.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pagina_v4/css/estilo.css"> -->
</head>
<body>

    <?php include 'menu.php';  ?>

<div class="container">

    <div class="" id="contenido">

        <?php   
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$components = parse_url($url);
parse_str($components['query'], $results);
echo($results['idsecretaria2']."<br>");
$id22=$results['idsecretaria2'];

// echo $url;
// $components = parse_url($url);
// parse_str($components['query'], $results);
// echo($results['pagina2']);


        // $enlace_actual = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        // echo $enlace_actual;
        //      $id= $_GET["idsecretaria"]; // id de tabla fechasectocentral
        //      $id22= $_GET["idsecretaria2"];// id de tabla sectorcentral
        //      // $secretaria= $_POST["secretaria"];// id de tabla sectorcentral
                

                // echo "$id";
                // echo "$id22";
                // echo "$secretaria";
                
                include_once "conexionbd.php";

                # Cuántos productos mostrar por página
                $productosPorPagina = 3;
                // Por defecto es la página 1; pero si está presente en la URL, tomamos esa
                $pagina = 1;
                if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) {
                    $pagina = $_GET["pagina"];
                }
                # El límite es el número de productos por página
                $limit = $productosPorPagina;
                # El offset es saltar X productos que viene dado por multiplicar la página - 1 * los productos por página
                $offset = ($pagina - 1) * $productosPorPagina;
                # Necesitamos el conteo para saber cuántas páginas vamos a mostrar
                $sentencia = $base_de_datos->query("SELECT count(*) AS conteo FROM fechasectocentral where id_secretaria=2");
                $conteo = $sentencia->fetchObject()->conteo;
                # Para obtener las páginas dividimos el conteo entre los productos por página, y redondeamos hacia arriba
                $paginas = ceil($conteo / $productosPorPagina);
                
                # Ahora obtenemos los productos usando ya el OFFSET y el LIMIT
                $sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("SELECT * FROM fechasectocentral where id_secretaria=2 ORDER BY fecha_de_modificacion desc LIMIT ? OFFSET ? ");
                $sentencia->execute([$limit, $offset]);
                $productos = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                # Y más abajo los dibujamos...
                ?>
                
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        
                        
                        <table class="table ">
                            <thead>
                        
                                <th width="250"><center><h5>Nombre de la Institucion</center></th>
                                <th><center><h5>Observacion o comentario</center></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                              
                            
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php foreach ($productos as $producto) { ?>
                                
                                <!--  -->
                                <?php 
                
                                $x=1;
                                $i = 0; 
                                $max_cols = 6;
                
                                                        
                                        if($i==0||($max_cols == 0)){
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                        }
                                        
                                        
                                        echo "<td>". $producto->secretaria."<br>Fecha: ". $producto->fecha_de_modificacion."<br></td>";
                                        echo "<td>". $producto->comentario."<br></td>";
                                        
                                        if(($i%($max_cols-1)==4 && $i!= 0)||$i == ($conteo-1)){
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                        $i++;
                                
                                
                                
                                ?>
                                
                                    
                                
                            <?php } ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <nav>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                
                                    <!-- <p>Mostrando <?php echo $productosPorPagina ?> de <?php echo $conteo ?> productos disponibles</p> -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <!-- <p>Página <?php echo $pagina ?> de <?php echo $paginas ?> </p> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <!-- Si la página actual es mayor a uno, mostramos el botón para ir una página atrás -->
                                <?php if ($pagina > 1) { ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="./detalles_org_proceso.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1 ?>    ">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                
                                <!-- Mostramos enlaces para ir a todas las páginas. Es un simple ciclo for-->
                                <?php for ($x = 1; $x <= $paginas; $x++) { ?>
                                    <li class="<?php if ($x == $pagina) echo "active" ?>">
                                        <a href="./detalles_org_proceso.php?pagina=<?php echo $x; ?>">
                                        
                                        <?php 
                                        
                                        
                                        ?>
                                            <?php echo $x ?></a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <!-- Si la página actual es menor al total de páginas, mostramos un botón para ir una página adelante -->
                                <?php if ($pagina < $paginas) { ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="./detalles_org_proceso.php?id22=<?php echo $id22;?>?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el error está en como separas los distintos parámetros en la URL que construyes para cambiar de página. En la URL los parámetros aparecen después del símbolo ? y se separan con &.

La URL que tú construyes

```
"./detalles_org_proceso.php?id22=<?php echo $id22;?>?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>"
```

debería ser

```
"./detalles_org_proceso.php?id22=<?php echo $id22;?>&pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1 ?>"
```

[Lo cual puedes simplificar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75296/para-qu%C3%A9-sirve-en-php) como

```
"./detalles_org_proceso.php?id22=<?=$id22 ?>&pagina=<?=($pagina + 1) ?>"
```

Por último id22 no es muy identificativo como nombre de parámetro o variable. Si es un id de secretaria, habría que llamarlo idSecretaria.